# What's the diffrence between DatagramPacket.getData().length and DatagramPacket.getLength() in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

In the code segment below,

```
DatagramPacket rPacket
rPacket  = new DatagramPacket(new byte[2000], 2000);
.. do some socket.receive ..
```

what would be the difference between DatagramPacket.getData().length and DatagramPacket.getLength() in java

Comment: look at either the source code or javadocs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first returns the size of the array used to construct the object, which never changes; the second returns the smaller of the length supplied to the constructor and the actual length of the smallest datagram most recently received, which changes on every receive.

Comment: @AlexWien It returns the length supplied to the constructor if you haven't received into it. If you have, it returns the length received if smaller, otherwise the length supplied to the constructor. That's what I call a minimum: your definition may vary. Further, if you keep receiving into the same object without resetting it, the length available to receive into keeps shrinking to the smallest packet received so far. That I also call a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

From javadoc of class DataGrammPacket

getLength(): `Returns the length of the data to be sent or the length of the data
received.`

getData(): `Returns the data buffer. The data received or the data to be sent
      starts from the <code>offset</code> in the buffer, 
      and runs for <code>length</code> long.`

furthe you have to know the
setData():

```
 Set the data buffer for this packet. This sets the
     * data, length and offset of the packet.
     *
     * @param buf the buffer to set for this packet
     *
     * @param offset the offset into the data
     *
     * @param length the length of the data 
     *       and/or the length of the buffer used to receive data
 setData(byte[] buf, int offset, int length)
```

The Constructor also calls the setData()

Comment: The last sentence contradicts the first sentence, and should be deleted.

Comment: This is original javadoc docu, i dont see a contradiction. Please remove the downvote, and think again

Comment: There *is* no contradiction now that you have completely rewritten your answer.

Comment: I have added the info about what length is related but not changed the original text.